# How to calculate dimensions of a HTML formatted JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jradiobutton, preferredsize

I am designing a Swing form using the GUI builder of Netbeans, and I'm using HTML to word wrap a `JRadioButton`. That works, but now the encapsulating `JFrame` does not resize the JFrame to fit the contents. I'm using the default GUI builder's LayoutManager, `GroupLayout`.

I tried to calculate the height of the component after it is word wrapped by HTML. That worked (see code below), but after setting the size and preferred size of the `JRadioButton`, the window does not get resized.

How can I fix it?

```
private void recalculateSize(JComponent component, int width) {
    View v = (View) component.getClientProperty(javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML.propertyKey);
    float preferredSpan = v.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
    int height = component.getHeight();
    float margin = height - preferredSpan;

    Dimension actualSize = getActualSize(component, width);
    int actualHeight = (int) (actualSize.height + margin);

Dimension d = new Dimension(component.getPreferredSize().width, actualHeight);
    component.setPreferredSize(d);
    component.setSize(d);

    // This height is the real height. I tested it setting the background
    // color to red.
    System.out.println("Actual height: " + actualHeight);
}

private static Dimension getActualSize(JComponent component, int width) {
    View view = (View) component.getClientProperty(javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML.propertyKey);
    view.setSize(width, 0);
    float w = view.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS);
    float h = view.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
    return new java.awt.Dimension((int) Math.ceil(w), (int) Math.ceil(h));
}
```

Below is the whole code. Since it is generated by the GUI builder, it it hard to remove the unnecessary code.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.text.View;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Test() {
        initComponents();
        initMoreComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        one = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        two = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        three = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        four = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        five = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        six = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        seven = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        eight = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        nine = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        ten = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        eleven = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        twelve = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        thirteen = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        fourteen = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        fifteen = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        sixteen = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        seventeen = new javax.swing.JButton();
        eightteen = new javax.swing.JButton();
        nineteen = new javax.swing.JButton();
        twenty = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        twentyone = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 420));
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));

        four.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        four.setText("Four");
        five.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        five.setText("Five");
        one.add(seven);
        seven.setSelected(true);
        seven.setText("<html>A very long sentence, which might take up more than one line.</html>");
        one.add(eight);
        eight.setText("<html>Another multiline sentence.</html>");
        nine.setText("Nine");
        ten.setText("Ten");
        eleven.setText("Eleven");
        twelve.setText("Twelve");
        thirteen.setText("Thirteen");
        fourteen.setText("Fourteen");
        fifteen.setText("Fifteen");
        sixteen.setText("Sixteen");
        seventeen.setText("Seventeen");
        eightteen.setText("Eightteen");
        nineteen.setText("Nineteen");
        two.add(twenty);
        twenty.setText("<html>Twenty with another line of text</html>");
        two.add(twentyone);
        twentyone.setText("Twenty one");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(three)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(seventeen))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(six)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(eightteen))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(nineteen))
                .addComponent(eight, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(nine)
                            .addComponent(four)
                            .addComponent(five)
                            .addComponent(ten)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(fourteen)
                                    .addComponent(fifteen))
                                .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(twelve)
                                    .addComponent(thirteen))))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(eleven)
                            .addGap(67, 67, 67)
                            .addComponent(sixteen)))
                    .addGap(0, 101, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addComponent(seven, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(twenty)
                        .addComponent(twentyone, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(nine)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(seven, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(twenty, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(twentyone)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(eight, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addComponent(four)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(three, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(seventeen))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(five)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(six, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(eightteen))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(ten)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(eleven)
                .addComponent(sixteen))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(fourteen)
                .addComponent(thirteen))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(fifteen)
                .addComponent(twelve))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(nineteen)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

        pack();
    }

    private void initMoreComponents() {
        recalculateSize(this.seven, 280);
    }

    private void recalculateSize(JComponent component, int width) {
        View v = (View) component.getClientProperty(javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML.propertyKey);
        float preferredSpan = v.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
        int height = component.getHeight();
        float margin = height - preferredSpan;

        Dimension actualSize = getActualSize(component, width);
        int actualHeight = (int) (actualSize.height + margin);

        Dimension d = new Dimension(component.getPreferredSize().width, actualHeight);
        component.setPreferredSize(d);
        component.setSize(d);
        component.revalidate();

        System.out.println("Actual height: " + actualHeight);
        System.out.println("Dimension preferred and set size: " + d);
        System.out.println("Dimension after revalidate: " + component.getPreferredSize());

        pack();
    }

    private static Dimension getActualSize(JComponent component, int width) {
        View view = (View) component.getClientProperty(javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML.propertyKey);
        view.setSize(width, 0);
        float w = view.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS);
        float h = view.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
        return new java.awt.Dimension((int) Math.ceil(w), (int) Math.ceil(h));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }

    private javax.swing.JCheckBox eleven;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox fourteen;
    private javax.swing.JButton eightteen;
    private javax.swing.JButton seventeen;
    javax.swing.JTextField six;
    private javax.swing.JLabel five;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton twentyone;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox fifteen;
    private javax.swing.JButton nineteen;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton seven;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup one;
    private javax.swing.JLabel nine;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton twenty;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup two;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton eight;
    javax.swing.JTextField three;
    private javax.swing.JLabel four;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox sixteen;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox thirteen;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox twelve;
    private javax.swing.JLabel ten;                
}
```

Comment: How can I fix it? - by post an SSCCE / MCVE short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame and JRadioButton labeled by Html, (I hope that isn't about add JRadioButton to JEditorPanel)

Comment: `pack()` "Causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents."

Comment: @mKorbel That's not easy, since it is code generated by the GUI builder.